# how do I stop maven version ranges from using snapshots

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am using version ranges in my maven POM:

```
<version>[3.0.0,)</version>
```

and for this particular artifact there is a 3.0.0 version in the repo and a 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT. When I try to do a release it fails as the SNAPSHOT version is used.

I have tried to get round this by editing my settings file to dis-allow the use of snapshots but it still fails:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>EFX Nexus Repository</id>
        <url>myUrl</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Thanks

Comment: This problem has been discussed for a long time here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3092... My advice for now is: Don't use ranges.

Answer (score 6):

This is basic maven issue.

When u fire multiple commands in single line..say mvn versions:resolve-ranges clean install...it will fetch SNAPSHOT when do release build.

Try with seperate execution of command.

first run mvn versions:resolve-ranges and then clen install

Answer (score 0):

I think that a SNAPSHOT version of the artifact has reached your local maven repository (in `~/.m2`) before you disabled snapshots in `<repositories>`. Now Maven is not able to download snapshots, but it is still able to use them from local storage.

Clean you `~/.m2` directory and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I had already deleted all local content from my Repo.

Comment: @Roaders And Maven continues to download SNAPSHOT versions from repository (foreign one, not local)??

Comment: Yup! That's what I found odd!

Comment: Have you seen in the Maven output something like "Downloading http://myUrl/path/artifact-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.*"? Maybe it is grabbing the artifact from a different repository then you have tweaked in your settings.xml. If it is indeed downloading the incorrect version from the repo in which you have  disabled SNAPSHOTs, you should file a Maven bug, because this is not the correct functionality and you won't find an answer here. Also, have you tried this with Maven 3 or tried upgrading your version of Maven 2? Maybe this has been fixed already if it was a problem.