# Jenkins deploying artifacts to Artifactory. maven-metadata.xml shows incorrect version for release and does not show versions for snapshot

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I am new to Jenkins and Artifactory and I have been unable to resolve this issue. I am using Jenkins 2.32.1, Artifactory 4.14.0, the Jenkins Artifactory plugin 2.9.0, and Maven 2. I am building using the Jenkins pipeline.

Here is my `jenkinsfile`:

```
node('default') {
    try{
        def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'https://artifactory.com/artifactory', credentialsId: 'MYCREADENTIALS'
        def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()


        stage('Checkout') {
            checkout myProject
        }

        stage('Artifactory configuration') {
            rtMaven.tool = 'Default'
            rtMaven.resolver server: server, releaseRepo: 'my-repo-all', snapshotRepo: 'my-repo-all'
            rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: 'my-repo-local', snapshotRepo: 'my-repo-local'
        }

        stage('Clean') {
            rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean '
        }

        stage('Install') {
            def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'install '
            server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
        }

    } catch (err) {
        echo "Caught: $err"
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    }
}
```

My Artifactory repo looks like:

- my-repo-local

  - ....
  - 8 (a release version)
  - 11-20170126.182450-1 (a snapshot version)
  - maven-metadata.xml

Here is a snippet from my `pom.xml` of the snapshot version:

```
<groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project-local</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>11-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>my description</description>
```

Here is the `mavan-metadata.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-project-local</artifactId>
  <version>11-20170126.182450-1</version>
  <versioning>
    <latest>11-20170126.182450-1</latest>
    <release>11-20170126.182450-1</release>
    <versions>
      <version>4</version>
      <version>5</version>
      <version>6</version>
      <version>7</version>
      <version>8</version>
      <version>11-20170126.173903-1</version>
      <version>11-20170126.182450-1</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20170126192233</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

My issue is that the `maven-metadata.xml` file is listing the snapshot version as its latest release version, and something (Artifactory?) is not recognizing the `11-20170126.182450-1` version is actually a snapshot version.

This creates issues when this repo is listed as a dependency in the `pom.xml` of my other projects. When it tries to grab the latest version from this repo, it incorrectly tries to grab the snapshot version (11-...) rather than the release version (8).

Thank you in advance! I appreciate any advice or insight into this problem.

Comment: Why should it? This is expected behaviour. (This is why in Artifactory, you should separate the snapshot repository from the release repository.) What is the actual problem with this snapshot version?

Comment: @Tunaki The snapshot version is created fine. The maven-metadata.xml file causes issues when this repo is listed as a dependency for one of my other repos. When it tries to grab the latest version from this repo, it tries to grab the snapshot version (11-...) rather than the release version (8). From the maven-metadata documentation, it appeared that the latest and release tags in my .xml should be 8 and it should also include a tag for the snapshot version. Here is the documentation for reference: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-repository-metadata/repository-metadata.html

Comment: That is normal also, if you're using a range to get the latest version... it includes snapshots, by design. Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407055/how-do-i-stop-maven-version-ranges-from-using-snapshots

Comment: @Tunaki I didn't realize these were expected behaviors. I switched from using ranges to get the latest version to using the exact number. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah... version ranges are very tricky, and perhaps it is better to avoid them at all...

Comment: @Tunaki I think you are right. I did a little more reading about them just now and that seems to be the consensus. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered in the comments of my question by @Tunaki. I was using ranges in my pom.xml to reference the artifacts from the repository mentioned in my post. I switched to using the exact version number and it is working correctly now.