# Maven version ranges : release vs snapshot version

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

With Apache Maven 3.3.9, We are using maven ranges for some dependencies version resolution as there are a lot of maven modules in my application an keeping the specific dependency version and changing to each release is bit pain.

To ilusstrate the structire of current application its like

**pom.xml (parent)**

```
<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>parentpom</name>
<modules>
    <module>../myapp-service</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.someotherapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>someotherappA</artifactId>
        <version>[1.1.0, 1.2.0)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.someotherapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>someotherappB</artifactId>
        <version>[1.1.0, 1.2.0)</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**pom.xml (child module)**

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
        <version>[0.0.1,2.0.0)</version>
        <relativePath>../myapp/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.myapp.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>myapp-service</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.someotherapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>ssomeotherappA</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.someotherapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>someotherappB</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

EXPECT : I expect the child module should pick the last released dependency version(no snapshot) like someotherappA-1.2.0 and not the latest version ´someotherappA-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT´

**PROBELM** : If available dependency version in artifactory are  like ´someotherappA-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT´(latest snapshot) and ´someotherappA-1.2.0´(stable release), then maven artifact ´myapp-service´ pick SNAPSHOT dependencies rather release version,even tough i am specifying `-DallowSnapshots=false` which means snapshot versions are not allowed in maven version ranges.

Here is what i am using to build my child module

```
mvn versions:resolve-ranges -f "myapp-service/pom.xml" -DgenerateBackupPoms=true -DallowSnapshots=false -DprocessDependencyManagement=false -DprocessParent=true

mvn clean install
```

I found similar problem here [how do I stop maven version ranges from using snapshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407055/how-do-i-stop-maven-version-ranges-from-using-snapshots) and seems there is an open bug in maven https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3092 . However, I am looking possible workaround or solution if someone bypassed this similar problem.

Comment: First recommendation do not use version ranges.

Comment: Version ranges are usually considered bad practise. Instead, the recommendation is to use the `versions` plugin to update versions.